# Number Theory Using Vieta Jumping

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all positive integers $1<a<b$ such that $$\frac{a^2+b^2-1}{ab}$$ is an integer.
$$$$Suppose that $a, b$ is a solution with $a+b$ minimized. Now we get $$a^2+b^2-1=kab$$ for some positive integer $k$. Treating this as a quadratic in $b$ we see that one root is $b$ and let the other root be $b_1$ then from the Viet's formula we get $$b_1=ka-b$$ and also $$b_1=\frac{a^2-1}{b}$$. The first equation shows that $b_1$ is an integer and the second equation shows that $b_1$ is positive as $a^2>1$, and hence we get $$b_1=\frac{a^2-1}{b}<\frac{a^2}{b}<\frac{b^2}{b}=b$$ and as $a, b_1$ is also a solution with $a+b_1<a+b$, so a contradiction.So there are no solutions for this equation for $1<a<b$ according to Vieta Jumping. But there are infinitely many solutions to this equation such as $(k, k+1$ for any $k>1$
$$$$So My Question Is Where Did I go Wrong??

Comment: But is $a <b_1$ also satisfied?

Comment: But why we need $a<b_1$ we have just find a $b_1$ such that $a+b_1<a+b$

Comment: Because you assumed $a <b $. You want the new solution to satisfy the same requirements as the old.

Comment: @darij gringberg https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping in the section standard Vieta Jumping it was assumed that $a>b$ but the second root $x_2$ was less than $a$ but was not greater than $b$

Comment: Ah, so you're assuming $a < b$ as a WLOG assumption, not as part of the problem.

Comment: But do you have $1 < b_1$ ?

Comment: Oh thanks. I got my answer